# Why does my windows program die with its frozen (bluish gray) Forms or windows?

Tags: windows, delphi, win32-process

My delphi program (NOT for .NET) on windows 7 seems to be running for couple of days straight and then the program sort of freezes with all of its windows painted with blueish grey color as if its windows are disabled. You simply don't have control over the program anymore but has to kill its process and start it up again. You don't need to reboot the system itself.

Has anyone experience this or anything similar? If so, what did you do to resolve or try to resolve it?

Thanks,

Comment: You'd better clarify your question. It's very vague now. Include relevant code, so that it can be reproduced & debugged.

Comment: This is an indication that the application has stopped processing messages. Perhaps it's stuck in an infinite loop (for instance, iterating through rows in a database with `while not MyDataSet.Eof do` and hitting a branch that prevents it from calling `MyDataSet.Next`, so you're sitting on the same row in the data and never reaching the `MyDataSet.Eof` condition that would break out of the loop.

Comment: @ Everyone Is this not a legitimate, reasonable and appropriate question for StackOverflow? How is it vague or not understandable? How can I provide piece of code, when I don't even know what is causing it? still, some of you answered and commented. Something to think about. Thanks

Comment: Digitalanalog, you have asked people what the problem in *your program* is. Nobody can know that with debugging *your* code. If you had just asked what kind of problem your symptoms might indicate, then Ken's comment would have been the answer. But you asked for a cure instead of a diagnosis. At least, the question title asks for that. The questions in the body are just vague.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bluish grey color is probably the default window color, meaning the window is no longer painting itself. This is consistent with the other symptom that the program no longer responds to any input. This means it isn't processing any window messages.

The easiest way to debug is to run the program in a debugger, and when it's hung just stop it and see where it's at.

If you have a memory leak you may eventually run out of memory in your process space, and it's possible that the program doesn't properly respond to that condition. Check Task Manager to see the amount of memory it's using.

Comment: Delphi handles explicitly out of memory errors and report them to the customer. So I do not think about this to be the cause of the issue.

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez, thanks for that information. The rest of my answer is still useful I hope.

Comment: Yes, it is: the main point is the application GDI messages loop not processed any more. :)

Answer (score 4):

Your question context is very vague. We do not have any information about your application, even its design and architecture.

Nethertheless, my (general-purpose) suggestions are the following:

- If your application is not multi-threaded, do the process in background threads, then leave the main thread ready to process GDI messages;
- If your application is multi-threaded, take care that all VCL access from background threads are made via a `Synchronize` call;
- If your application is multi-threaded or use timers, take care that no method is re-entrant (in some circonstances, you may come into a [race condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition));
- Hunt any memory leak;
- Use a detailed logging of the program execution, [logging all exceptions](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2011/04/14/Enhanced-logging-in-SynCommons) risen, to guess the context of the program hang (it may be used on the customer side also to hunt race conditions);
- Download the great free tool named [ProcessExplorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) (now hosted by Microsoft), and check out the state of your frozen program: you will see detailed information about threads, CPU use, memory, network, libraries, handles - this is a must have for any serious debugging - track especially the *GDI handles* leaks (number of those should remain stable);
- If you did not check it already, take a look at the global Windows system event log: there may be some information here;
- Perhaps a third party component or library is responsible of the process hang: try to isolate the part of your code which may be responsible of this hang.

I've Delphi application running for months without any problem. Issue is definitively in application code, not in the Delphi architecture (its RTL and VCL are very stable).

Comment: I agree with you. I don't think there is anything wrong with the delphi itself but in my program. I am trying to get some idea as to why my program is acting the way it is. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I fixed several hangs and other problems in the past years.

I used ProcessExplorer before (to view the stack), but it needs Microsoft debug symbols. And with Delphi you can only create a .map file. With map2dbg I could convert the .map to a .dbg, but this does not always work (note: .dbg is deprecated, newer versions of Microsoft debugging tools do not use them anymore).

So I made my own tool :-)
It is part of "AsmProfiler Sampling" tool:
http://code.google.com/p/asmprofiler/downloads/detailname=AsmProfiler_Sampling%20v1.0.7.13.zip
Click on the "Stack view of Process" button in the [first screen](http://code.google.com/p/asmprofiler/wiki/AsmProfilerSamplingMode).
Then select your process from the list and double click on it:
http://code.google.com/p/asmprofiler/wiki/ProcessStackViewer

Now you can view the stack trace of each thread. If the GUI does not respond, the main thread hangs, so check the first thread. (note: sometimes you see an "emtpy" stack because a function misaligned the stack for calculation etc, use the raw strack tracing algoritm to get more the full stack again (with a lot of false positives, because every pointer on the stack which is possible a function is shown!)). 
Please post the stack here if you can't solve it, so we can take a look at it.

Note: it uses the jclDebug.pas unit of the JEDI library, so it can read .map and .jdbg files (also .dbg and .pdb debug files of Windows dlls) and also internal JCLDEBUG sections (embedded .jdbg file in one .exe). So you must at least build an .exe with detailed (!) map file, see Project Options -> Compiler -> Linking.